# Laptop beeps on startup after battery drains

Tags: boot, laptop, motherboard, bios, battery

I have a laptop (an Alienware 13) and I recently found out a problem with it. When the battery drains (i'm not really sure if it's instant, or long time after battery drains), I charge it and then I try to turn it on.

Then nothing is shown on the screen and I start hearing some strong beeps (groups of 5 beeps). I shut it down and then try to turn it on again. The following message is shown:

> Real Time Clock Error.
>   System CMOS Checksum bad
>   Time-of-day not set - please run SETUP program.
>   Strike the F1 key to continue, F2 to run the setup utility

The laptop starts working well afher this and i don't see any other problem, but I don't know why is this happening. I want to know if this is serious trouble, and how to fix it (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Disregard the first post. Thats not your laptop or the battery. This can be quite involved if you have never taken a laptop apart. If this is your first time, take some Solo cups, mark them in order of the step from the instructions. Put the screws you remove in the cups & make sure you download the "service manual" for your laptop.

The 13 series has a rechargable cmos battery. They are a real pain in the butt to replace.
https://www.partspeople.com/blog/2017/01/06/dell-alienware-13-p56g001-cmos-battery-removal-installation/

The cr2035 is not the correct battery.

Comment: Forgot to add this, no this will not cause serious trouble. You will have to reprogram  the system time every time the computer is turned off.

Comment: I love how you downvoted my post and then posted the same solution. Thanks friend. :/

Comment: Sorry, Your answer was wrong. I'm not trying to make you feel bad. But if you update your answer I wll delete my post. You have an answer for a totally different series of laptop. Which has a totally different cmos battery. And totally wrong instructions to disassemble